# Is it possible to split the bibliography into two different parts using BibTeX type definitions?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

I have quite a lot of bibliography entries and I have to separate normal entries (e.g. `@book`, `@article`, etc.) from internet entries (`@misc`) due to formal requirements of my university.

I know it's somehow possible to do this using `biblatex`:

```
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\defbibheading{b}{\section{Books}}
\defbibheading{i}{\section{Internet}}
\printbibliography[heading=b,keyword=book]
\printbibliography[heading=i,keyword=internet]
```

I currently have a document of around 80 pages and I dont want to switch if possible. Are there any known approaches for BibTeX to do this?

Comment: The documentation of biblatex describes many incompatible (with biblatex) bibliography packages at the very start of its documentation (§ 1.5.4).  I've used none of them, but it mentions: bibtopic, bibunits, chapterbib,  multibib, splitbib.  That said, do yourself a favour and switch now, rather than later when it is that much harder to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really* don't want to switch to `biblatex` right now, here's an example how to split the bibliography using the [`splitbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitbib) package. It requires to set up bibliography categories and to assign entries to those categories in the document preamble. (Alternative solutions are [`bibtopic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) which requires different `.bib` files for the different categories and [`multibib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multibib) which features category assignment via in-text citations.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{splitbib}

\begin{category}{Books}
\SBentries{A01}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{Internet}
\SBentries{B02}
\end{category}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@online{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]