# natbib bibliography/references section SPLIT into sections

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, subdividing

I have a Bibliography section which I'd like to split into sections, like this:

- References

  - Conference and workshop proceedings

    - Reference 1
    - Reference 2
  - Journal articles

    - Reference 3
    - Reference 4
  - Internet Engineering Task Force Request For Comments (IETF RFCs)

    - Reference 5
  - Application Programming Interfaces (APIs)

    - Reference 6

I use commands such as these to build my references:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\renewcommand*{\refname}{}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{myReferences}
```

end then:

```
/home/robottinosino$ latex f && bibex f && latex f && latex f
```

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54940/is-it-possible-to-split-bibliography-into-2-different-parts-using-bibtex-type-de

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it that all or your bib entries are in a single file, right? If so, have a look at the [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/) package. It performs its job by providing separate citation commands to distinguish citations in different bibliographies. It is compatible with the `natbib` package. In the preamble, you'd issue a series of `\newcites` commands, such as

```
\newcites{conf}{Conference and workshop proceedings}
\newcites{journ}{Journal articles}
\newcites{ietf}{Internet Engineering Task Force Request For Comments (IETF RFCs)}
\newcites{apis}{Application Programming Interfaces (APIs)}
```

In the body of the document, you would use commands such as `\citetconf{ref1}` and `\citepietf{ref2}`, where `ref1` would be a document to be listed under the heading  "Conference and workshop proceedings" and `ref2` would be a document to be listed under the heading "Internet Engineering Task Force Request For Comments (IETF RFCs)".

Assuming the bib entries are in a file called `myReferences.bib`, the bibliographies would be generated by providing commands such as

```
\bibliographyconf{myReferences}
\bibliographyjourn{myReferences}
```

and so on. The package even lets you assign different bibliography styles to each of the separate bibliographies.

Incidentally, if your bib entries are already located in different bib files (organized by type), you may want to take a look at the [bibtopic](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibtopic/) package as well.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! How can I change the style of the heading it produces through \renewcommand{\refname}{Test}.

Comment: Each time you issue one of the `\bibliography<xxxx>` commands, a new unnumbered section should be created with the heading (title) defined in the second argument of the corresponding `\newcites{<xxxx>}{<Some Title>}` macro.

Comment: I guess then the question should be rephrased as "how can I format -that- unnumbered section it auto-generates?".

Comment: @Robottinosino - which aspects of the formatting of the section header do you wish to modify? There are quite a few parameters; presumably you only need to change a few of them, right?

Comment: Absolutely, correct. Size, emphasis (bold vs plain)... I have tried doing something like \renewcommand{\refnamereferencedproceedings}{\small FIXME} but I don't know how to make FIXME stand for "what the command would normally output here". Perhaps there's a better way..

Comment: @Robottinosino - please provide more information about your document, in particular, the document class you use (article? report? book? something else?). This'll affect how the appearance of a section header for a bibliography is defined (and hence how it should be redefined).