# Problem with multibib combined with natbib

Tags: natbib, multibib

I am having trouble with splitting references by section. I have tried following the first answer [to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63921/natbib-bibliography-references-section-split-into-sections), as it seems to be the most fitting to my case. However, after I do, latex does not find the reference (Citation undefined). I don't find the mistake in what I am doing wrong.

Here is a reproducible example where the Taylor_Herman_1971 reference does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{vars}{Some title here for the second set of references}

\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}

\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Some text and two references \citep{Kriesi_Grande_Lachat_Dolezal_Bornschier_Frey_2008, Kriesi_Grande_Dolezal_Helbling_Hoglinger_Hutter_Wuest_2012}.

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{biblio_cee_appendix.bib}

\section{Second section}

Some other text and one new reference \citetvars{Taylor_Herman_1971}, as well as one of the old references \citepvars[][p. 364]{Kriesi_Grande_Lachat_Dolezal_Bornschier_Frey_2008}.

\bibliographyvars{biblio_cee_appendix.bib}

\end{document}
```

And this is how biblio_cee_appendix.bib looks like:

```
@book{Kriesi_Grande_Lachat_Dolezal_Bornschier_Frey_2008, address={New York:}, title={West European politics in the age of globalization}, ISBN={978-0-521-89557-6}, publisher={Cambridge University Press}, author={Kriesi, Hanspeter and Grande, Edgar and Lachat, Romain and Dolezal, Martin and Bornschier, Simon and Frey, Timotheos}, year={2008} }

@book{Kriesi_Grande_Dolezal_Helbling_Hoglinger_Hutter_Wuest_2012, address={Cambridge; New York}, title={Political Conflict in Western Europe}, ISBN={978-1-107-62594-5}, publisher={Cambridge University Press}, author={Kriesi, Hanspeter and Grande, Edgar and Dolezal, Martin and Helbling, Marc and Höglinger, Dominic and Hutter, Swen and Wüest, Bruno}, year={2012}, language={English} }

@article{Taylor_Herman_1971, title={Party Systems and Government Stability}, volume={65}, ISSN={0003-0554}, DOI={10.2307/1955041}, number={1}, journal={The American Political Science Review}, author={Taylor, Michael and Herman, V. M.}, year={1971}, pages={28–37} }
```

Comment: Have you run `bibtex vars`?

Comment: what do you mean? how do I do that? I just compiled it like I always do...

Comment: I have solved it by changing the order in which packages are loaded. No idea why this makes a difference, but it works now:
\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{vars}{Some title here for the second set of references}

Comment: Note that it will help a bit if you list which editor you use (or if you use OverLeaf). Some editors (or OverLeaf) runs bibtex/biber automatically others do not.