# Separate bibliography for articles

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I have a bibliography that mixes every refrence type (mostly books and articles together). Now, I would love to be able to separate only the articles from the rest and display them under a separate bibliography subtitle, e.g. "Articles".

Is this in any way possible?

I use

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

for my bibliography and cite with the following commands:

```
\newcommand\mycite[2][]{%
  \citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})\ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
  \newcommand\myfootcite[2][]{\footnote{\mycite[#1]{#2}}}
  \def\prevcite{} % initialize \prevcite
%% macro for in-text citation
\newcommand\tcite[2][]{%  
  \def\newcite{#2} 
  \ifx\prevcite\newcite 
    Ibid.%
  \else%
    \gdef\prevcite{#2}% update \prevcite
    \citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})%
  \fi
  \ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
%% macro for in-footnote citation
\newcommand\fcite[2][]{\footnote{\tcite[#1]{#2}}}
```

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you looked into the [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/) package?

Comment: `biblatex` can do that: it has a `\defbibfilter` command which allows , among other things, to filter references by entry type. See §3.6.10 opf the documentation.

Comment: @Bernard No need to create filters with `\defbibfilter` just use the `type` and `nottype` options of `\printbibliography`.

Comment: @Guido: I just wanted to insist on the possibility  of creating filters.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the biblatex examples on CTAN or from the TeXLive distribution. This possible solution is based on those examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{death-star,
    author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
    title        = {Death Star},
    howpublished = {Alderaan and Yavin 4},
    year         = {0 BBY}
  }
  @misc{death-star-2,
    author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
    title        = {Death Star II},
    howpublished = {Endor},
    year         = {4 ABY}
  }
  @article{abc,
    author       = {Abc, D.},
    title        = {The Letter Fantasies},
    year         = 1492,
    keywords     = {one}
  }
  @Book{efg,
    author       = {Efg, H.},
    title        = {Alphabet Soup},
    year         = 1942,
    keywords     = {two}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
%   style=authoryear, % uncomment to display author-year
]{biblatex}
\defbibfilter{other}{
  not type=article
}
%
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
They first built \emph{Death Star}~\autocite{death-star}.

The design flaw was found in \autocite[Lemelisk et al., Chapter 3, p. 123][]{death-star}.

To address the flaw, they designed \emph{Death Star 2}~\autocite{death-star-2}
that featured many smaller diameter heat exhaust vents.

Read the letter fantasies \cite{abc} or stories from the a-soup \cite{efg}.
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Articles},type=article]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Other Sources},filter=other]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need to define a filter. Biblatex provides the `nottype` option for `\printbibliography` (and it can be used multiple times).

Comment: @zun: This is exactly what I am looking for. However, I am completely lost at how to implement this as I don't use biblatex. How should I go about finding a solution?

Comment: @MadJens : is switching to biblatex an option? If so, you should have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots .

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Is there no way to do this with natbib? Maybe a possibiliy manually creating two bibliographies with the bibtexkeys?

Comment: @Madjens: a similar question and a response using bibtex appears at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54940/is-it-possible-to-split-the-bibliography-into-two-different-parts-using-bibtex-t. That might help, if you can't use biblatex.