# Separate bibliography for articles: adendum - entries with capital letter gives an error (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, subdividing

This is question is actually a question to an answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219594/separate-bibliography-for-articles), but since my rep is too low, I have no other option than to ask it like this. The question from that link goes like this:

*I have a bibliography that mixes every reference type (mostly books and articles together). Now, I would love to be able to separate only the articles from the rest and display them under a separate bibliography subtitle, e.g. "Articles".
Is this in any way possible?*

someone called Zun answered the question that it is possible with biblatex, and a working example would be this:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{death-star,
    author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
    title        = {Death Star},
    howpublished = {Alderaan and Yavin 4},
    year         = {0 BBY}
  }
  @misc{death-star-2,
    author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
    title        = {Death Star II},
    howpublished = {Endor},
    year         = {4 ABY}
  }
  @article{abc,
    author       = {Abc, D.},
    title        = {The Letter Fantasies},
    year         = 1492,
    keywords     = {one}
  }
  @Book{efg,
    author       = {Efg, H.},
    title        = {Alphabet Soup},
    year         = 1942,
    keywords     = {two}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
%   style=authoryear, % uncomment to display author-year
]{biblatex}
\defbibfilter{other}{
  not type=article
}
%
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
They first built \emph{Death Star}~\autocite{death-star}.

The design flaw was found in \autocite[Lemelisk et al., Chapter 3, p. 123][]{death-star}.

To address the flaw, they designed \emph{Death Star 2}~\autocite{death-star-2}
that featured many smaller diameter heat exhaust vents.

Read the letter fantasies \cite{abc} or stories from the a-soup \cite{efg}.
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Articles},type=article]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Other Sources},filter=other]
\end{document}
```

and this works flawlessly. *As long as the entry-type is written with small letters*. However, I use JabRef, and it formats my references with a capital letter, like @Online, @Book etc. In Zuns working example above, the entry @Book is with a capital letter. Try substituting @article with @Book. Suddenly it gives the error:

```
./untitled.tex:48: LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 48.
```

Since all of my entries are with a capital letter, this is most unfortunate. Is there anything that can be done about this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well, it's a warning only...

Comment: Thank you :) Well, yes, it is a warning. But it is warning with the result that the bibliography that it warns about doesn't get printed, only the other bib, with the filter=other.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I tried all lowercase `@<whatever>`, all uppercase, some uppercase and some lowercase; I switched the first `@article` to `@Book`.  No problems (after running, of course, the full sequence of `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`). You might need to elaborate.  My versions: `biblatex v2.9a` and `biber 1.9`.

Comment: It works like a charm here as well. (`biblatex 2.9a` with `biber 1.9` on an up-to-date MikTeX.) What I noticed though is that your bibcheck construction is superfluous you can just use `nottype=article` instead of `filter=other`.

Comment: Okay, that is strange. Just updated texlive, I have biblatex 2.9a and biber 1.9 on my lubuntu 14.04 system. will try on a w7 machine later today, see if it's the same.
Moewe: nice tip with the nottype instead, thank you!

Comment: It's the same on my w7 installation. That's odd. What system's are you guys running?

Comment: Just checked again with a recent MikTeX distribution on Windows 7 with up-to-date `biblatex` 2.9a, Biber 1.9. The only warnings appearing is "Setting 'defernumbers=true' recommended." Since the OP did not get back with more information and the problem was not reproducible, I voted to close.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to give more information, it's just that I am at loss as to what kind of information would help to understand why I get the errorcode and you didn't. I could try again on a friends PC, or I could just accept that I got a problem noone else has...